# How do I outer join multiple tables using linq to entities

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, code-first

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 with Entity Framework CodeFirst

I have two classes as follows:

Question:

```
public class Question
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Target Target { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public Unit Unit { get; set; }
}
```

Answer:

```
public class Answer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

I also have this ViewModel:

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string QuestionType { get; set; }
    public string Target { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

I want to query the questions table and include the answers, if there are any.

I've been trying this style

```
        var question = (from q in hontgen.Questions
                        where q.ID == id
                        join qt in db.QuestionTypes on q.QuestionType equals qt
                        join t in db.Targets on q.Target equals t
                        join c in db.Categories on q.Category equals c
                        join u in db.Units on q.Unit equals u
                        join a in db.Answers on q.Answers equals a

                        select new QuestionViewModel() {
                            ID = q.ID,
                            Question = q.QuestionText,
                            QuestionType = qt.Type,
                            Category = c.CategoryName,
                            Unit = u.UnitName,
                            Target = t.TargetName,
                            Answers = a
                        }).Single();
```

But this of course doesn't roll, because a isn't a list of answers, but only one answer.

How do I rewrite the query to take all answers in the collection, or all answers with the correct question in "Question", while at the same time accepting an empty answers-list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about a sub query like the following

```
public class DataRepository
{
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Answer> Answers { get; set; }

}


public class QandA
{

    DataRepository dr = new DataRepository();

    public void QueryQuestion(int id)
    {
        var question = (from q in dr.Questions
                        where q.ID == id

                        select new QuestionViewModel()
                        {
                            ID = q.ID,
                            Question = q.QuestionText,
                            Answers = (from a in dr.Answers 
                                        where a.Question == q
                                        select a)
                        });
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick reply, I'm trying it out right now (my code is a bit messy at the time, but I'm sorting it out). It compiles fine and looks as it would do the job. However, what if i have no answers, what will happen to the .ToList()?

Comment: I keep getting this.. Any ideas?
`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Models.Answer] ToList[Answer](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Project.Models.Answer])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: In the Repository What if you make List<Answer> Answers into IEnumerable<Answer> Answers; then you dont call the ToList() function and the query will run.  Then if you need the funcionality of a list later you can use Answers.ToList() outside of the Linq to Entities query.

Comment: Hi again, I did what you said (more or less) but I get an exception: `Unable to create a constant value of type 'Project.Models.Answer'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.` Can't get my head around this.. Any clue this time too? Can't objects be enumerable?

Comment: Yes, whenever you use "var" on a Linq to Entities or Linq to Objects the result is actaully interpreted as IEnumerable<T> where T is any primitive or Object.  (I think Linq to Sql "var" would be IQueryable<T>)

Comment: If you code is still similar to the query above I would think that the problem is this line "join a in db.Answers on q.Answers equals a". You are joining db.Answer a (a single answer from db) with Question.Answers that is an IEnumerable or List. I would remove the original join of the answers in the initial join. Using something like I suggested you do not need Answers in the initial join expression and it is the only One to Many relationship in the Join expressions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. Yes, I have moved to your approach, leaving the answers out of the initial query, but I'm still stuck with the `Unable to create constant value` exception.

Comment: Looks like there is a known issue [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx)
  - Referencing Non-Scalar Variables Not Supported Referencing a non-scalar variables, such as an entity, in a query is not supported. When such a query executes, a NotSupportedException exception is thrown with a message that states "Unable to create a constant value of type EntityType. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context." --

Comment: To work around this try using property of the entity on your joins  instead of the entire entity. for example join to Targets on the Id field instead of on the entity.  Example 'join t in db.Targets on q.Target.TargetId equals t.TargetId

Comment: I moved the answers-query out of the questions-query, and it's sort of working now. +1 for the link also, good reading!